# Deleting of old endpoint profiles from admin ui

Tags: iot, endpoint, kaa

How I can to delete endpoint profiles from Admin-UI? Because I have a lot of old endpoints which does not work and not valid list of endpoints a bit annoying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This possibility will be added in new version 0.10.0.
Here link to the [ticket](http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/KAA-1030) in jira.
You can use code from develop branch if it’s ability critical for you.